# How to solve 'attempt to invoke virtual methods' of ViewModel

Tags: java, android

I've making an android app with bottom navigation. There's a main activity and three items on the navigation menu, three of each corresponds to a fragment. In the 'modeFragment', I've add a "add button" to switch to a new fragment, which I name it 'NewNoteFragment', in this fragment I can enter words and press the 'save' button to turn back to 'modeFragment'.

I have used viewmodel and room database so far, and I implement only one function --> 'insert' function to insert my data into the database.

While I run the app, the demo app crashes when I press the save button. I wonder if it is the viewmodel's problem, but I can't find any solution online.

I am a newbie in developing Android app and I don't have a clue to how to fix the problem.

This is the code where the problem is.

```
noteViewModel.insert(note);
```

This is modeFragment

public class modeFragment extends Fragment {

```
private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;
private TextView mTextTitle;
//private static final int NEW_NOTE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;


public modeFragment() {
    // Requires empty public constructor
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mode, container, false);
    mTextTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Yeah man");
    if(bundle != null) {String note_description = bundle.getString("etNewNote");
        //final String note_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println(note_description);
        Note note = new Note(note_description, NOTE_ADDED);
        System.out.println(note.getNote());
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Don't make me do this");
        noteViewModel.insert(note);
        //TextView firstText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etNewNote);
    }


    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            NewNoteFragment newNotefragment = new NewNoteFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "I love you");
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_mode, newNotefragment);
            Log.d("MainActivity", "I hate you");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        });

    NoteViewModel noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mTextTitle.setText("Fire in the home(x) hole(o)!");
    // Setup any handles to view objects here
    // EditText etFoo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFoo);
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name

};}
```

This is 'NewNoteFragment'

```
public class NewNoteFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public static final String NOTE_ADDED = "new_note";


private EditText etNewNote;

public NewNoteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_note, container, false);

    Log.d("MainActivity", "Dancing is great");
    etNewNote = view.findViewById(R.id.etNewNote);
    Button add=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etNewNote.getText())){
        return;
    }else {
        String first = etNewNote.getText().toString();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("etNewNote", first);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        modeFragment ModeFragment = new modeFragment();
        ModeFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        fragmentTransaction.hide(this);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, ModeFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

}

This is NoteViewModel class

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel{
private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

private NoteDao noteDao;
private NoteRoomDatabase noteDB;
public NoteViewModel(Application application) {

    super(application);
    noteDB = NoteRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    noteDao = noteDB.noteDao();
}

public void insert(Note note) {
    new InsertAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}
@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();
    Log.i(TAG, "ViewModel Destroyed");
}

private class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {

    NoteDao mNoteDao;
    public InsertAsyncTask(NoteDao mNoteDao) {
        this.mNoteDao = mNoteDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
        mNoteDao.insert(notes[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

This is the "Note" class

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
```

public class Note {

```
@NonNull
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

@NonNull
public String getNote() {
    return this.mNote;
}

@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
private String description;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "note")
private String mNote;

public Note(String description, String note){
    this.description = description;
    this.mNote = note;
}
```

}

This is the logcat Debug session and the error

```
Process: com.demo.iot, PID: 16605
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.demo.iot.NoteViewModel.insert(com.demo.iot.Note)' on a null object reference
    at com.demo.iot.modeFragment.onCreateView(modeFragment.java:57)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:310)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1185)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Thank you for you help in advance, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate the viewmodel before call them

Try `onCreateView` like follow

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mode, container, false);
    mTextTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.test);

    //Instantiate the viewmodel before call them
    noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Yeah man");
    if(bundle != null) {String note_description = bundle.getString("etNewNote");
        //final String note_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println(note_description);
        Note note = new Note(note_description, NOTE_ADDED);
        System.out.println(note.getNote());
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Don't make me do this");
        noteViewModel.insert(note);
        //TextView firstText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.etNewNote);
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            NewNoteFragment newNotefragment = new NewNoteFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "I love you");
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frag_mode, newNotefragment);
            Log.d("MainActivity", "I hate you");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```